# passing information from a activity to a service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-activity

I am using the alarm manager to call a service at a later time where I want to update a file at a user specified time. That mechanism works fine. What I need to do now is pass to the service which alarm has called it as I have multiple alarms with different intents which needs to do different things at different times.

I understand how to pass extras with bundles, but it doesn't seem to work with services. I cant pass anything to it this way, I keep getting `null` as what was passed from the activity to the service.

Here is my activity code for 1 alarm.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("extraData", "FIRST_ALARM");
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);    
PendingIntent AmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Time2fire, fONCE_PER_DAY, AmPendingIntent);
```

Service Code:

```
super.onStart(intent, startId);
String bundleFromActivity = intent.getStringExtra("extraData");
```

I've searched a lot, but nothing I've seen has worked.

ok so now I changed it to this:
from my activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerService.class); 
intent.putExtra("someKey", "hifromalarmone");    
PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),0,intent, 0);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Time2fire, fONCE_PER_DAY, myIntent);
```

from my service
I realize now that onstart is deprecated and onstartcommand must be used.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId, int flags) 
{   
super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
String data1 = extras.getString("somekey");// intent.getStringExtra("someKey");
return START_STICKY; 
}
```

and guess what.... still returns a null. What am i missing here??? Looks like im not passing something right.

ok, so I figured it out... after a lot of digging and a little good luck I realized that merely updating the data inside of my intent was not enough as my original intent was already registered with the system. As such it was never updated with my new passed data. Here was the key,(hope someone finds this useful)
The following line of code is what needed to be updated
PendingIntent AmPendingINtent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,myIntent,0);
If you update the last 0 to something else since the last time this was registered with the system it forces the intent to update and pass along your bundle.

PendingIntent AmPendingINtent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,myIntent,654654);// something like this.

Comment: Is this Java for Android? Might benefit from some appropriate tags.

Comment: correct. i added someother tags for this thanks!

Comment: You might want to check my tutorial here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/ I sent a boolean extra with the intent

Answer (score 0):

In your first scenario

Your using [putExtras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29):

```
 myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

you should use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29):

```
myIntent.putExtra(bundle);
```

putExtras is for some other purpose, like cross app intents or something

---

in your second scenario you put the key in using:

```
 "someKey"
```

you then try and retrieve it using:

```
 "somekey"
```

They aren't the same causing your null.

---

In a shameless plug I have a very nicely architectured and clean OO example of notifications and services here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Comment: thank you! I did notice this and changed it to somekey/somekey.Also found out that adding PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT inside of my pending intent also fixes it.